# post value from one page to multiple page in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

referral-page.php

I have submitted email data and store in DB and then goto Primary page

```
<form action="store-db.php">
   <input type="text" name="email" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I have stored email data in DB using ajax ( this was completed ). but I want to post email value to **primary-page.php**

**primary-page.php**  ( email field should be prefilled if I come from referral otherwise it should be empty value )

```
<form action="thank-you.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you get it from the DB?

Comment: i want data who are come of referral page only, that data (db) do not use in primary page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myself form action changed to primary-page.php

```
<form action="primary-page.php" id="primary_page">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

 1) data validate and stored in DB using ajax ( store-db.php ) 
 2) email value post to primary-page.php using function frm_submit()

var form_validate = $("#primary_page");
form_validate.validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
           required: true,
           email: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
    var param = form_validate.serialize();
    var btn_submit = $("#submit");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/store-db.php',
        data: param,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
           frm_submit();
        }
   });
});


function frm_submit() {
  form = document.getElementById('primary_page');
  form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the ajax call to the DB has succeeded, why not just redirect to the thank you page, sending the email address in the query string ($_GET)?

Or maybe better: just submit to the php page and do the db storage there, before outputting "thank you" or "error"?

Comment: i want data who are come of referral page only, query string may be misuse in primary page

Comment: I would say: referral page submits to primary-page.php. Si you can check the email address, save it in de DB if necessary and output the thankyou form.